# What does it mean when apriori min support = 0.05? and how does this differ from min support = 0.5?

Tags: apriori

I used python for apriori but I was confused seeing **min support = 0.05** in many models. Doesn't this mean **min support is only 5%** and how can this be relied on when discovering the existing patterns in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.05 refers to 5%, which means the fraction of transactions with probability of item 'A' and 'B' occurring together as compared to the total number of transactions is 5 out of 100.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/market-basket-analysis-127c73f353d7